# Serial communication from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, serial-port

Is it possible to communicate over a machine's serial port through JavaScript?

I have to write a short program that sends data to a microcontroller over the serial port that has a GUI and is cross-platform compatible, and I really don't want to use Java's Swing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JavaScript itself doesn't have any built in functionality to allow you to access the serial port. However, various JavaScript engines (v8, rhino, etc) allow you to write your own custom native objects.

You might want to check out node.js, which is a JavaScript library for v8 that's focused on writing server-side code (rather than web browser client code). It seems that someone's already written a serialport package for that:

https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

Comment: But why we can access ordinary webcam without need 'server-side code''?

Comment: @Buzz probably because of the APIs provided by modern web browsers, e.g. [WebUSB](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) and [Media Capture and Streams](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html). See [whatwebcando.today](https://whatwebcando.today/) for some neat examples. These are not features of the programming language (JavaScript) itself but rather the environment in which it executes.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but in case this helps anyone else, Chrome Apps have access to a serial API - http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html - which might help.

It's Chrome specific (obviously..), but Chrome is available cross-platform so might answer the question.

Comment: I think this is Chrome OS specific, doesn't work in Chrome (browser).

Comment: Now it actually is possible to use in Chrome, the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API

Answer (score 3):

There's a cross platform plugin for serial port communication called [jUART](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **it's possible using an ActiveX**(I did it). You can make an activeX and use JavaScript to invoke it.
If you prefer, you can make a .net dll and register it using regasm. Take a look at this [link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/WritingAnActiveXControlInCSharp.aspx)

You also can write an activeX using VB6 and register it. Both works fine.
Ps.: if you are using ActiveX, the JavaScript code will run just on IE.

Comment: I wrote a little code to send/get information to/from a modem with a GSM chip.

Comment: This isn't actually using JS - you're using JS to invoke methods of an ActiveX component.

Comment: It works fine. JavaScript makes an interface between browser and COM(on Internet Explorer). I wrote a code to get ICCID of a GSM chip through an website.

Comment: "cross-platform compatible" that excludes the possibility of using ActiveX. Also, ActiveX is not javascript and it not adding a javascript object to access the serial port.

Comment: @Vismari That's not the point. The question was whether or not it's possible through JS, which it isn't natively.

Comment: Obvious natively it's impossible. But if you **need** make a communication to serial port's in a client/server enviroment you can use ActiveX + JavaScript(IE) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DLL library (this includes e.g. most Windows APIs) that allows you to communicate over serial port you can invoke it from Firefox chrome code (or content code with universalxpconnect privileges) by using [ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/ctypes.jsm).

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use a Java applet that connects to the local computer's Java application that reads the serial port. The applet would then transfer the data to a JavaScript class or something that can hold the information. Then additional JavaScript code can be used to access the data. It's a complicated solution but should work.

Another way is to create a POJO service.

Comment: There are a couple libraries available that do this: free [rxtx](http://www.rxtx.org/), and paid [serialio](http://www.serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php).