# HTML5 serial port access?

Tags: html, serial-port

Is there a way to have a HTML5 page access the serial port of a device, all client-side? I know this can be done with Java applet but I would like to know if it can be done with HTML5.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640953/serial-communication-from-javascript

Answer (score 6):

It cannot.  Browsers do not allow access to the port without the use of a plugin.

Answer (score 4):

google chrome has a javascript API to do that (http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html)
but it is browser specific, no HTML5

Answer (score 1):

No. And neither can JavaScript. You are mixing Java (applets) and JavaScript. They have nothing to do with eachother.

Comment: I don't think the OP was "mixing" them.  The question seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: I saw that. I thought I kept my answer anyway, because it (still) causes confusion.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was rather telling @ghoti that than you :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs - I see.  I came to this question after "JavaScript applet" had been edited, so your answer didn't make any sense.