# How to replicate pyserial sending RGB values to Arduino in jUART?

Tags: javascript, arduino-uno, pyserial

I have been using [pyserial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial) in a locally running Python application to send RGB values to an Arduino with:

```
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

ser.write(struct.pack('>3B', red_value, green_value, blue_value))

# where the rgb values are ints like 77,75, 0
```

I'd like to now achieve this functionality from a non-local website.

[jUART](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART) seems to be designed for this purpose, ie a:

> Cross platform browser plugin for serial port communication from
>   JavaScript

It requires the user to create a plugin for the system and browser they are using.

I've followed the instructions on their [main GitHub page](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART) as far as I could, but I don't really understand the parameters enough to define their values, and I haven't made a browser plugin before so not sure if I am missing something.

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Firefox 48 for Ubuntu` and have copied:

[bin/Linux/npjUART.so](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART/blob/master/bin/Linux/npjUART.so)

to:

```
~/.mozilla/extensions
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Serial Test</title>
<script src="serial.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** (serial.js)

```
//Get a Serial object
var ser = plugin().Serial;

// Open a port
ser.open("/dev/ttyACM0");

// Set port options
/*
baud: Baud rate

parity: 0->none, 1->odd, 2->even

csize: 5 6 7 8

flow: 0->none, 1->software, 2->hardware

stop: 0->one, 1->onepointfive, 2->two
*/

var baud = "";
var parity = "";
var csize = "";
var flow = "";
var stop = "";

ser.set_option(baud, parity, csize, flow, stop);

// Send a byte to serial port
char = "";

ser.send(char);
```

**Questions**

01)  What should the empty values in the above Javascript be?

02)  Do I additionally need to follow the `To Build` [instructions](https://github.com/billhsu/jUART)?

03)  Is there anything else I need to do to get `jUART` to replicate the original `pyserial` program shown above?

**Edit:**

Based on user suggestion to look at pyserial defaults and then replicate them, they seem to be here:

https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial

```
__init__(port=None, baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS, parity=PARITY_NONE, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, write_timeout=None, dsrdtr=False, inter_byte_timeout=None)
```

So perhaps jUART variables would therefore be:

```
var baud = 9600;
var parity = 0;
var csize = 8; // based on user comment
var flow = 0; // based on user comment
var stop = 0;
```

When I open the `html` file with the above values in the `js` file, I get the following in Firebug:

> ReferenceError: plugin is not defined

**Arduino Sketch:** (for reference)

```
// digital output pin numbers
const int digitalOutputPinForRedLED = 9;
const int digitalOutputPinForGreenLED = 10;
const int digitalOutputPinForBlueLED = 11;

// global variables
int valueOfRed = 0;
int valueOfGreen = 0;
int valueOfBlue = 0;
int x = 1;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  // set digital pin modes
  pinMode(digitalOutputPinForRedLED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digitalOutputPinForGreenLED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(digitalOutputPinForBlueLED,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()) {
    if (x==1) {
     valueOfRed = Serial.read();
     Serial.print("Red: ");
     Serial.println(valueOfRed);
     analogWrite(digitalOutputPinForRedLED, valueOfRed);
   }
    else if (x==2) {
     valueOfGreen = Serial.read();
     Serial.print("Green: ");
     Serial.println(valueOfGreen);
     analogWrite(digitalOutputPinForGreenLED, valueOfGreen);
   }
    else if (x==3) {
     valueOfBlue = Serial.read();
     Serial.print("Blue: ");
     Serial.println(valueOfBlue);
     analogWrite(digitalOutputPinForBlueLED, valueOfBlue);
   }
   x++;
 }
    else {
      x = 1; 
     }
delay(1);
}
```

Comment: Based on the python code baud is obviously 9600. All the other values appears to be defaults in pyserial. Read the pyserial docs for what the default parity and stop bits are. Flow control is generally none unless you are using flow control. And data size (csize) is generally 8 bit unless you really are talking to a very old 7 bit device.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, the only thing you missed was adding the plugin to the PLUGINS directory. Copy the already compiled plugin from the git to ~/.mozilla/**plugins**/ instead of ~/.mozilla/**extensions**